# How to move UIScrollView to the active UITextField while the device is laying flat?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield, cgrect

Okay, so I am stumped on this one.  I'm using keyboard notifications and a UIScrollView to scroll to the current active text field when it is tapped.  It works exactly as expected in both portrait and landscape **EXCEPT when the device lays flat**.

In Landscape orientation, if the device is held in the air it scrolls as expected, but when the device is laid flat on a table and a text field is tapped the view scrolls completely off screen.

What causes this?

I am testing on an iPad Mini and iPhone 5 using iOS7.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

     // Register for keyboard notifications
    [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];

    // keep track of scrollview insets for later
    scollViewIndicatorInsets = self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets;
}

- (IBAction)editingEnded:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) {
        kbSize = CGSizeMake(kbSize.height, kbSize.width);
    }

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(65.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES];
    }
}



// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
   // UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(65.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of the keyboard size is much more complicated than it should be. Let the API do the work for you:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGRect kbFrame = [info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    // Convert the keyboard frame from the window to the scrollview
    kbFrame = [self.scrollView convertRect:kbFrame fromView:nil];
    CGSize kbSize = kbFrame.size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(65.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES];
    }
}
```